# Console Program crashes when run from Windows Service

Tags: batch-file, windows-services, console-application

I am using a Windows Service to run my batch file on scheduled times. The batch file runs an `.exe` file that is a `Console` application that simply shows a message and creates a file on a folder. When I run this program manually, the program works and the file is created. But when I try to run the program via my Windows Service the program crashes (or in some cases it asks for permission which is not good).

If I do not use the Console in my program however (nothing shown to the user and everything done in the background), the file is correctly created. I need to make sure that the service runs my .exe/.bat files but it looks like running executable files are a bit risky with services.

Is there a way to solve this problem or should I change my program so that it only does things in the background and does not display anything?

Comment: Show the code in your service that launches the application.  You probably just need CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or something.

Answer (score 0):

Is your service being run in the LocalSystem account -- the default for all Windows Services? If so, then your console application is being launched in that same account, where it may not be able to find its settings.

Try providing your Windows account on the service's [Log On tab](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService) to see if that gets around the problems. Be sure to set an account where the console application runs normally!

Comment: no unfortunately even when I provide the logged in user information it still crashes. I also tried "enable to interact with the desktop".

Comment: Can you identify where the crash is happening? In what operation?